# Algorithms and Datastructures - Am I solving these complexity questions right?

Tags: c#, algorithm, time, complexity-theory, space

This is my first post, so I am sorry if I could've done something better, please tell tho ;)

I am currently practicing for Algorithms and Data structures, and we need to calculate Time and Space complexity. For some reason I find it pretty hard and can't get any confirmation/guidance if I'm going the right way or totally the wrong way. So I thought I'd give it a go here.

The First method I'm trying to solve is the following:

```
static void f1(int n) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < i * i; j++) {
      for (int k = 2; k < j; k++) {
      System.out.println("*");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Time complexity**
The steps I made so far:
The first for loop has a time complexity of O(n), because of the i < n, it iterates n times.
The second for loop has a time complexity of O(i^2) because of the j < i*i, it iterates i^2 times.
The third loop does j-2 times, because k=2, so I think.. it is O(j) complexity

So I am not sure if all of the above is correct, but now the step is to multiply all the complexities, so the total complexity would be Big O(n * i^2 * j) which then would be i^2?

So if I'm doing this right it would be **Big O (i^2) time complexity.**

**Space complexity**
I'm not too sure how to start with the space complexity but I guess it is just Big O(j) because it is only saving the function call and the for loops, which is O(1) and the printing of the last for loop is the j - 2 times that the printline is called.
I'm totally unsure if this is the right way to think but if not, it's also good for me to know ;)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers cannot be correct because they mention variables `i` and `j` which don't appear in the input. Clearly any correct answer must only mention `n`.

The outer-most loop has an iteration count linear in `n`, whereas the two inner loops both have iteration counts that grow with `n^2`, so the three loops nested together are `O(n^5)`. Since the argument of the `println`-statement is independent of `n`, it's `O(1)`, and hence we have `O(n^5)` in total for time complexity.

As for space complexity, there are only three single-valued counting variables declared in the function, so it's `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The innermost loop has the `O(j)` time complexity, right.

Now the middle loop is a bit more tricky. It runs from `i` to `i^2`, and each iteration is linear in terms of `j`. You may express it as `Sum[i..i^2] j`. This is a sum of an arithmetic progression. Recall that `Sum[a..b] j = O(b^2 - a^2)`. Substituting limits (`a = i, b = i*2`) obtain the middle loop complexity `O((i^2)^2 - i^2) = O(i^4)`.

Finally, the outer loop runs from `0` to `n`, and each iteration is `O(i^4)`. It is important to know that the sum of polynomial of degree `k` yields the polynomial of degree `k+1`. This means that the time complexity of the entire function is **`O(n^5)`**.

Regarding space complexity, it cannot possibly be `O(j)`, because `j` is a free variable. It doesn't exist outside the function. Try to prove that it is `O(1)`.